# ExpandableListView does not appear when Activity starts

Tags: android, expandablelistview

*Yayy, coding is so much fun. This is my third attempt at creating an ExpandableListView that is linked to a sqllite db. The last version worked ok when retrieving data, but not so great when I needed to delete or edit an item. It was based off of the Api Demo, expandableListView 1 and 2. The Api code suggested that I store my info in an array before it could be put into a ExpandablelistView. I think we can all see an issue with deleting and updating items that are stored in an array. I decided to start over, with something much cleaner.*

**The following code is my attempt at creating an activity that fills an expandableListView with sqllite db values. However, nothing happens when the activity starts, not even an exception.**

I assume that my problem lies within browseView.setAdapter(mAdapter); but I really don't know what Im'm talking about and have no way to prove it! If I change the above to a listadapter it throws a nullpointerexception.

Lastly, it should be noted that my getChildren cursor passes my groupCursor straight though. This is only because I haven't figured out what goes in here! Babysteps.

Am I on the right track here? Thanks for taking a look.

```
public class BrowseActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

final private String[] asColumnsToReturn = {
    Items.ITEMS_TABLE_NAME + "." + Items.ITEMS_ITEM,
    Items.ITEMS_TABLE_NAME + "." + Items.ITEMS_DESC,
    Items.ITEMS_TABLE_NAME + "." + Items.ITEMS_ID };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.browse);
DbHelper dbh = new DbHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
queryBuilder.setTables(Items.ITEMS_TABLE_NAME);
ExpandableListView browseView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

Cursor mCursor = queryBuilder.query(db, asColumnsToReturn, null, null,
        null, null, Items.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
startManagingCursor(mCursor);


SimpleCursorTreeAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorTreeAdapter(this,
        mCursor, R.layout.row, R.layout.exprow,
        new String[] { Items.ITEMS_ITEM }, new int[] { R.id.txtItem },
        R.layout.exprow, R.layout.exprow, new String[] { Items.ITEMS_DESC },
        new int[] { R.id.dscItem }) {

    @Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {


        return groupCursor;
    }
};

browseView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


}

}

***START NEW OF NEW CLASS FILE***

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {


private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DB_NAME = "itemList.db";



DbHelper(Context context) {

super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}   

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Items.ITEMS_TABLE_NAME + " (" 
   + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," 
   + Items.ITEMS_ITEM + " TEXT," + Items.ITEMS_DESC + " TEXT," 
   + Items.ITEMS_MANU + " TEXT," + Items.ITEMS_UPC + " TEXT," +
   Items.ITEMS_NWEIGHT + " TEXT," + Items.ITEMS_AWEIGHT + " TEXT)");

}

 @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db){
super.onOpen(db);
}
}

***START OF NEW CLASS FILE***
public class ItemDatabase {

private ItemDatabase() {
}

public static final class Items implements BaseColumns {

private Items() {
}

public static final String ITEMS_TABLE_NAME = "table_itemList";
public static final String ITEMS_ID = "_id";
public static final String ITEMS_ITEM = "item";
public static final String ITEMS_DESC = "description";
public static final String ITEMS_MANU = "manufacturer";
public static final String ITEMS_UPC = "upc";
public static final String ITEMS_NWEIGHT = "netweight";
public static final String ITEMS_AWEIGHT = "actualweight";
public static final String DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER = "item ASC";
}
```

And the "browse" xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

<ExpandableListView 
android:id = "@android:id/list" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
></ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611927/simplecursortreeadapter-and-cursorloader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because I passed the Group cursor straight through the getChildrenCursor() method. You have to create a new Cursor inside the method.

```
@Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {

        String tempGroup = groupCursor.getString(groupCursor
                .getColumnIndex(Items.ITEMS_ITEM));

        DbHelper dbh = new DbHelper(BrowseActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();

        String sqlString = "SELECT " + Items.ITEMS_ID + ", "
                + Items.ITEMS_DESC + ", " + Items.ITEMS_MANU + ", "
                + Items.ITEMS_NWEIGHT + ", " + Items.ITEMS_AWEIGHT + ", "
                + Items.ITEMS_UPC + " FROM " + Items.ITEMS_TABLE_NAME
                + " WHERE " + Items.ITEMS_ITEM + "=" + "'" + tempGroup
                + "'";
        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(sqlString, null);

        return mCursor;

    }
```

And the Row Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView 
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right" 
android:id="@+id/txtItem" 
android:text="Item" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:textSize="15dip"

></TextView>


<TextView 
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right" 
android:id="@+id/dscItemTwo" 
android:text="Desciption" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:textStyle="italic"
android:textColor="#666666"

></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally the expRow Layout(*It's a little long, I have alot of table rows. I must admit things are poorly named too. I just wanted to get it working before I made it pretty!*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_span = "2"
android:stretchColumns="0"

>
<TableRow 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
android:layout_gravity="right" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
    <TableRow 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight = "1" 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    >
        <TextView 
        android:layout_marginRight="1dip" 
        android:textColor="#994020" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Manufacturer" 
        android:id="@+id/manuItem"
        ></TextView>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow11" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ></TableRow>

   </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    >
        <TableRow 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"


        >

            <TextView 
            android:layout_marginRight="1dip"
            android:textColor="#994020" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="right" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Description" 
            android:id="@+id/dscItem"
            ></TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
        ></TableRow>

     </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"


        >
            <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6" 

            android:layout_gravity="right" 
            android:baselineAligned="true">
                <TextView
                 android:layout_marginRight="1dip"
                 android:textColor="#994020" 
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                 android:layout_gravity="right" 
                 android:text="Net Weight" 
                 android:id="@+id/nWeightItem" 
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"


                  ></TextView>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7" 


            >
                <TextView 
                android:layout_marginRight="1dip"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text="ounces" 
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:id="@+id/textView1" 

                ></TextView>
            </TableRow>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:id="@+id/tableRow5" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         >
            <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow12"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            >
                <TextView 
                android:layout_marginRight="1dip" 
                android:textColor="#994020" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="right" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Actual Weight" 
                android:id="@+id/aWeightItem"
                ></TextView>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow13"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginRight="1dip"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text="ounces" 
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:id="@+id/textView111" 
                ></TextView>
            </TableRow>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
            <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right" 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow14"
            >
                <TextView 
                android:layout_marginRight="1dip" 
                android:textColor="#994020" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="right" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text="UPC" 
                android:id="@+id/upcItem"
                ></TextView>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow15"
            ></TableRow>
        </TableRow>


 </TableLayout>
```

Comment: I wish you had given the code for R.layout.row, R.layout.exprow. I am also trying to find out the same thing you did here.

Comment: Let me see what I can dig up.

Comment: Oh thanks so much I am trying to find the same thing. I posted a question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723626/expandable-listview-populate-from-local-sqlite-database

Comment: thanks atomSmasher for your effort for me, but is your database getting created ? because mine is not getting created with the same code. I pulled the database from sqlite browser and it is empty.

Comment: The code above only searches the database and displays. At the top of the method you will see **SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();** This calls a custom class that actually creates a db. Do you have anything like this?

Comment: okay, I have one project, but I was trying to run your this complete code and if it works fine for me then I will be able to understand it well and implement the same way for my project. I see if I do it exactly same way as mentioned here then a database table is getting created with total 7 columns, but nothing is added to them, so I do not see any list on the screen as well.

Comment: Gotcha, the problem is the code above is not complete, its only one class out of many! I have 8 or 9 other activities that are used to add items to the db. The db will be empty unless you A. create some textfields to send data or B. create a db on your pc and place in your devices data/data/.... folder and run.

Comment: oh okay I have those codes for my project, I will make changes in my project, but yes thanks in millions