# Expandable ListView populate from local Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, expandablelistview

I am looking for a tutorial for expandable list view using local sqlite database.

What I understood till now, is the following

```
private class MyTestList extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {

//The below is a constructor with 7 arguments with 3 for parent and 3 for child data ad layout

public MyTestList (Context ctx, Cursor groupCursor, int groupLayout,
        String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, int childLayout, String[] childFrom,
        int[] childTo) {
    super(ctx, groupCursor, groupLayout, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
}
```

My question is how do you get the parent cursor and child cursor and then link them to each other.

There is a API called

```
@Override
protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(final Cursor groupCursor) {

   //I suppose here I am passing the parent cursor and then retrieving the 
   //corresponding child cursor for the particular id ??

    NOT SURE HOW DO I FILL THIS, I THINK THIS WILL HAVE SOME STRING ARRAY WITH CHILD DATA
}
```

After this I should bind it with the ui, how do I do that. have been searching for long time not getting the stuff looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new cursor inside your getChildrenCursor just like you did for the group, but use a WHERE sql statement to be more specific in your pickings! See this [PAGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526439/expandablelistview-does-not-appear-when-activity-starts) for code sample.